# Cannot connect to TFS-2013 from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

My organization is using Team Foundation Server 2013. I'm using VS 2015 (Update 2).

There were no problems at all previously (past years), suddenly whenever i tried to get the same old projects from the Source Control Explorer, I'm getting the following error message window in VS 2015.

"Server was unable to process request. --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have already tried removing the workspace, server connection and recreating new connection to TFS server. It doesnt help. What should i do?

Comment: Try to install Team Explorer 2013 and connect with it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Object reference" error is the hardest to troubleshoot if you don't know exactly where the error is occurring.

Please use [/Log (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) and check vs log file: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml` whether contained some message.

You can also give a try with [delete VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) for these problems.